# Why sed and Perl are matching shortest string from the right

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed

I'm trying to extract the full path of the file on a line like this:

```
"2016-08-18 09:08:35.453 ERROR manager.impl.AuditManager (default task-149)         ISS:961|EXTERNALID:0182.1507.895.48259763|CAT:1|LOGID:75|DESCRIP:Exception while auditing postnodes: /data/bea/wls/92/repository/master_one/clients/961/082016/04/001001-0001-000000008746601.par_POSTNODES/audit_1471504114103_postnodes.xml:1:1: error: Unexpected end of file after null in org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3486) with original cause Unexpected end of file after null in org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.reportFatalError(Piccolo.java:1038)"
```

And I find that when I'm using sentences like

```
perl -pe 's#.*(/.*xml):1:1.*#\1#'
```

or the sed equivalent

```
sed 's#.*\(/.*xml\):1:1.*#\1#'
```

im just obtaining the shortest match from the right `"/audit_1471504114103_postnodes.xml"` and not the whole path from the first "/" (while other regex engines like the one from Notepad++ are behaving the standard and right way (greedy) and returning `"/data/bea/wls/92/repository/master_one/clients/961/082016/04/001001-0001-000000008746601.par_POSTNODES/audit_1471504114103_postnodes.xml")`

What is happening here? The behavior of the engine is different or there is some hidden configuration variable i'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quantifiers are greedy by default, consequence the first `.*` will match the largest possible string.

Comment: Ups, true. I put just the "(/.*xml):1:1" part in the Notepad++ regex search. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Change the regex to:

```
perl -pe 's#.*?(/.*xml):1:1.*#$1#'
              ^
```

To match the whole path.

Comment: Thanks, works for perl, not for sed...  "sed 's#.*\?\(/.*xml\):1:1.*#\1#'" is returning the same  "/audit_1471504114103_postnodes.xml"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of matching `.*`, match the string you really want: zero or more *non-slash* characters.

```
's#[^/]*\(/.*xml\):1:1.*#\1#'
```